# United Kingdom Difference between NN4B and NHS number

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens

Read something called NHS number that is like a unique identifier for people used by  hospitals. Also the heard that there is something called NN4B which assigns NHS numbers for babies.

Question: Is NHS number generated in a different way for newborns than for people in general? Or what is the difference between the way of generating these two numbers? If there is a difference other than the way of generating, what are they?

Comment: NHS is a National Health Service number assigned to any registered user of the public health services in England, Wales and the Isle of Man. NN4B is simply the name of a contract let to issue NHS Numbers for all Babies (NN4B) in those three countries. Are you asking how the numbers themselves are generated, as compared to how one would be generated for an adult immigrant? Or how they are generated at all? or what do the numbers themselves _mean_?

Comment: how they are generated at all, and are they generated differently (obviously the numbers are different but the mechanism) for new borns as opposed to other citizens? Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a question that applies equally to locals and expats, and unless edited or justified, does not appear to meet our terms in [help].  Closing as off topic for now.